# Will there be a successor to the Tentacles and Kraken conventions?

Tags: convention

The long-running Tentacles convention series —held at Castle Stahleck, Germany and centered on Chaosium games, chiefly Call of Cthulhu and the various Gloranthan games— ended in 2009.  A follow-up Chaosium convention, [THE KRAKEN](http://www.the-kraken.de/), was held in east Germany last year.   [An interview](http://jerome23.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/the-kraken-wakes-an-interview-with-fabian-kuechler/) of Fabian Küchler by Chris Romer gives a pretty good feel to what these conventions were about and their situation last year.

There's been talk of something similar for this year.  Will anything happen?

**Update**

Fabian's Twitter feed [has the following](http://twitter.com/_THE_KRAKEN_/statuses/26004828211642368):

> Help to decide when the next KRAKEN will take place and if it will have an 'ALL YOU CAN DRINK' Flatrate for booze (including Troll Grog)!

That suggests yes, time to be determined soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct. THE KRAKEN is a biannual event because it takes a lot of preparation and time. Mostly for the attendees to take time off work. The next KRAKEN is in the making:

THE KRAKEN

A Gaming Vacation

August 29 - September 3, 2012!

Schloss Neuhausen, Germany

[www.the-kraken.de](http://www.the-kraken.de)

[www.facebook.com/theKraken.de](http://www.facebook.com/theKraken.de)

[twitter.com/_THE_KRAKEN_](http://twitter.com/_THE_KRAKEN_)

We are always happy to meet new people - so give yourself a push. Thanks.

Fabian Küchler

Answer (score 2):

It's [just been announced by Fabian](http://twitter.com/_THE_KRAKEN_/status/47013601491427329):

> Save up your holidays and plan ahead for THE KRAKEN in Summer 2012 at Schloss Neuhausen, Germany! Registration will start August 2011!

So The Kraken is now the successor convention series to Tentacles, not a one-off as I had originally thought.  And it looks like it is every two years, not the annual event that Tentacles was.